# Unity how to instantiate a prefab from axis y = 260 to 10?

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

How can i instantiate objects, in 2d, from pos y 110 to downwards?

I'm still searching but i cant find any, so i put my question here, hope someone can help me.

EmployeeList.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class EmployeeList : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject EmployeeTab;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        // Create a parent of your instantiated objects
        GameObject parent = GameObject.Find("Recruit_Employee");

        // Position of the instantiated objects
        Vector3 position = Vector3.up * 110f;

        // Distance between instantiated objects
        float step = 50;

        employees.Add(new Employee("David", 5, 5000));
        employees.Add(new Employee("Jason", 10, 10000));
        employees.Add(new Employee("Donald", 3, 3000));



        foreach (Employee worker in employees)
        {
            // Instantiate the objects from a given prefab
            GameObject w = (GameObject)Instantiate(EmployeeTab, position, Quaternion.identity, parent.transform);
            w.SetActive(true);
            // Set the desired name
            w.name = worker.name;

            // Don't forget to change the position of the next employee
            position.y -= step;

            Debug.Log("Name: " + worker.name + "Skill: " + worker.skill + "Cost: " + worker.cost);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

And i want to put in an Instantiate in the `foreach` section, so if i have 2 employees then 2 buttons or prefabs has to be created which i call `EmployeeTab`
.

Im new to intermediate scripting :/

Employee.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class Employee : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string name;
    public int skill;
    public int cost;

    public Employee(string newName, int newSkill, int newCost)
    {
        name = newName;
        skill = newSkill;
        cost = newCost;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to instantiate it so far? Also, what are you trying to instantiate, a object? A text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know [how to instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html), it's a piece of cake ! ;)

```cs
void Start ()
{
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

    // Create a parent of your instantiated objects
    GameObject parent = new GameObject("EmployeesParent");

    // Position of the instantiated objects
    Vector3 position = Vector3.up * 110.0f ;

    // Distance between instantiated objects
    float step = 10 ;

    employees.Add(new Employee("David", 5, 5000));
    employees.Add(new Employee("Jason", 10, 10000));
    employees.Add(new Employee("Donald", 3, 3000));

    foreach (Employee worker in employees)
    {
        costInfo.text = "Cost: " + CurrencyConverter.Instance.GetCurrencyIntoString(Employee.Cost, false, false, false);
        EmployeeName.text = Employee.Name;
        SkillInfo.text = Employee.Skill.ToString();

        // Instantiate the objects from a given prefab
        GameObject w = (GameObject) Instantiate(myPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity, parent.transform );

        // Set the desired name
        w.name = worker.name ;

        // Don't forget to change the position of the next employee
        position.y -= step ;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT : MonoBehaviour can't be instantiated like a traditionnal C# class. Since your Employee class seems to be a simple datacontainer,  you must change your Employee class and the Start function I wrote :

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

[System.Serializable]
public class Employee
{
    public string name;
    public int skill;
    public int cost;
}
```

---

```cs
// YOUR OTHER SCRIPT

// Set the values from the inspector here
public Employee[] employees ;

void Start ()
{
    // Create a parent of your instantiated objects
    GameObject parent = new GameObject("EmployeesParent");

    // Position of the instantiated objects
    Vector3 position = Vector3.up * 110.0f ;

    // Distance between instantiated objects
    float step = 10 ;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < employees.Length ; ++i )
    {
        costInfo.text = "Cost: " + CurrencyConverter.Instance.GetCurrencyIntoString(employees[i].cost, false, false, false);
        EmployeeName.text = Employee.Name;
        SkillInfo.text = Employee.Skill.ToString();

        // Instantiate the objects from a given prefab
        GameObject w = (GameObject) Instantiate(myEmployeePrefab, position, Quaternion.identity, parent.transform );

        // Set the desired name
        w.name = worker.name ;

       // Add the component you want to the instantiated GameObject to show the information of your employee like a UnityEngine.UI.Text component or whatever you want

        // Don't forget to change the position of the next employee
        position.y -= step ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got nothing created, and i get an error saying NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Kalip did you make a public field for `myPrefab` and set it in the inspector?

Comment: I renamed myPrefab to EmployeeTab

Comment: And i have a prefab set in for the EmployeeTab.

Comment: Everything runs perfectly, only the instantiate not. Debug.log returns the correct values.

Comment: Ah, They did instantiated, but they are not active and enabled, and they are in the wrong position: `(-316.2427f, -194.4601f, 0f)` instead of `(3f, 112f, 0f)`

Comment: Updated my EmployeeList.cs above.

Comment: You did not understand anything to Unity components, I'm afraid. Employee seems to be a simple data container, but you try to use it as a Component (inheritance from MonoBehaviour), but **it's not possible** ! You can't instantiate a MonoBehaviour like that ! You must use `AddComponent` instead. You did not give enough information about your problem.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/3263c6f8baf3d5c61ceabad8bd8e622c They are at the bottom left corner instead of `(3f, 112f, 0f)`

Comment: I got them positioned by now, but how can i set their Name.text = to their name? and Cost.text ... etc.?

Comment: Simply find the various Text component using the [Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) function, and the [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) function